# 1003 error (unable to find an operator for alias ) in group function in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I have written a .pig file whose content is :

```
register /home/tuhin/Documents/PigWork/pigdata/piggybank.jar;
define replace org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.REPLACE();
define csvloader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();
xyz = load '/pigdata/salaryTravelReport.csv' using csvloader();
x = foreach xyz generate $0 as name:chararray, $1 as title:chararray, replace($2, ',','')  as salary:bytearray, replace($3, ',', '') as travel:bytearray, $4 as orgtype:chararray, $5 as org:chararray, $6 as year:bytearray;
refined = foreach x generate name, title, (float)salary, (float)travel, orgtype, org, (int)year;
year2010 = filter refined by year == 2010;
byjobtitile = GROUP year2010 by title;
```

The purpose is to remove `','` in dollar value in 2 columns and then group the data by jobtitle. When I am running this using run command there is not error. Even dumping of year2010 is working fine. But dumping byjobtitiel is giving error:

[error in dumping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DZTk.jpg)

The output of the log file is:

> Pig Stack Trace
>   --------------- ERROR 1003: Unable to find an operator for alias byjobtitle
>
> org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1003: Unable
>   to find an operator for alias byjobtitle  at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.buildPlan(PigServer.java:1544)     at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1029)     at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:997)    at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:910)     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:754)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:376)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)  at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:565)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

I am new to bigdata and dont have much knowledge. But it looks like there is a problem in data type. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to "CSVLoader" you are using. This will have  ',' as default delimiter. Since your data also has "," in some of its field like salary and travel, the positional index is getting changed. So if your data is something like this

> name  title   salary  travel  orgtype org year 
>       A   B   10,000  23,1357 ORG_TYPE    ORG 2016

then using  CSVLoader will make "A  B   10" as the first field, "000    23" as the second field and "1357   ORG_TYPE    ORG 2016" as the third field based on ","

```
register /Users/rakesh/Documents/SVN/iReporter/iReporterJobFramework/avro/lib/1.7.5/piggybank.jar;
define replace org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.REPLACE();
define csvloader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();
xyz = load '<path to your file>' using csvloader();
a = foreach xyz generate $0;


2016-06-07 12:28:12,384 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1<br>
(A  B   10)<br>
```

You can make your delimiter different so that it is not present in any field value.

Try using CSVExcelStorage. You can use its constructor to explicitly define the delimiter

```
register /Users/rakesh/Documents/SVN/iReporter/iReporterJobFramework/avro/lib/1.7.5/piggybank.jar;
define replace org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.REPLACE();
define CSVExcelStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage('|','NO_MULTILINE','NOCHANGE');
```

It will work fine as long as same identifier is not present as ;

- delimiter
- any field value

Comment: Your answer was desperately in need of editing. I made a first pass, but you should definitely sweep back through.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for editing. Will write my answers short and crisp henceforth

Comment: Yup, I hope it was at least somewhat helpful. I know nothing about Hadoop or Apache, so I appreciate you looking over my altercations.